# How can I pass script object as a parameter in apple script

Tags: applescript

```
script WordShortcutKeys
    on OpenDocument()
        tell application "Microsoft Word" to activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "o" using {control down, command down}
        end tell
    end OpenDocument
    on SaveSyncDocument()
        tell application "Microsoft Word" to activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "s" using {control down, command down}
        end tell
    end SaveSyncDocument
end script
set application_name to  "Word" & "ShortcutKeys"
application_name's SaveSyncDocument()
```

It shows below error
error

““WordShortcutKeys” doesn’t understand the “SaveSyncDocument” message.” number -1708 from “WordShortcutKeys”

Answer (score 0):

Speaking technically, when you write this construction in AppleScript:

```
script some_script_id
    [...]
end script
```

You are not naming a script-object "some_script_id". You are actually setting a variable called `some_script_id` to the script object that follows. `script some_script_id` is effectively equivalent to `set some_script_id to [...]`. AppleScript doesn't have a syntax for indirect reference to variables by name, so you cannot do what you are trying to do in the second to last line.  You can (of course) set one variable to another, e.g.:

```
set application_name to  WordShortcutKeys
application_name's SaveSyncDocument()
```

...but otherwise this is a limitation of AppleScript.

Also (so it's said), don't use GUI scripting unless you have no other choice. Word has built-in commands for opening and saving files. Using those built-in commands is far more efficient, flexible, and reliable than scripting the GUI; check out Word's scripting dictionary in the Script Editor and you'll see them.